# PHP directory not correct

Tags: php

I have a /controller/controller.php file that runs this code:

```
include('../model/model.php');
print page_load();
```

The model/model.php loads correctly and the page_load() function gets loaded. However, the model.php file still 'thinks' that it is in the controller directory. So if I try and do any POST actions in the model.php, it looks in the controller directory rather than the model directory.

Can I please have some advice on how to fix this?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In model.php your need set `action` in form with correct path to post it to your `model.php`

```
<form action="/model/model.php">
// bla-bla-input-bla-bla
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are still inside the controller page [1]. As suggested by the name the controller page simply includes the the model page. What Sergey said is partly correct. You need to to assign a more complete path to the form's action parameter. As I am sure you will see Sergey's answer does not work. This is because you need to go up one directory. This is done by including two dots that is `..` before the path.

```
<form action="../model/model.php">
```

You are already including the `..` in your include statement. Just use it in the same way.

Please let us know if you need more help. :-)

[1] http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [`chdir`](http://php.net/chdir/) function.
With it, you can change your current directory, allowing PHP to think you are in `model/` folder.